# How can I check if the input string is binary?

Tags: c

I need to check if the string contain a binary number., I tried this way with a for it worked for a while but then, I've got problem, it will be a my stupid error, but i need help!!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char input[16];
    int ndec=0,rem,nbin,base=1;
    printf("Insert a binary number \n-----> ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    nbin=atoi(input);
    while(nbin>1111111111111111){
        printf("THE NUMBER YOU ENTERED IS NOT TOO BIG \n Enter a smaller number n----> ");
    }
    int lun = strlen(input);
    for(int i=lun;i!=-1;i--){
        if (input[i] !=49 && input[i] !=48) {
            printf("The entered number is not a binary number!!  n Enter a binary number n----> ");
            scanf("%s", input);
            int lun = strlen(input);
            i =lun;
            }
    }
    nbin=atoi(input);
    int temp = nbin;
    while(temp > 0)
    {
        rem = temp % 10;
        ndec = ndec + rem * base;
        temp = temp / 10;
        base = base * 2;
    }
    printf("Decimal value is %d\n",ndec); 
}
```

Comment: `atoi` is the wrong function for this task. You'll want to use something like [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) where you can specify the base.

Comment: `scanf("%s", input);` without a field-width modifier is no safer than `gets()`  See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102). Failing to ***check the return*** someone could enter `"my cow"` and you would blindly process it as a number (and `atoi()` would silently fail returning `0` without any indication of an error) if `nbin > 1111111111111111` then you will enjoy unlimited output from `while(nbin>1111111111111111){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this way

```
void da_binario_a_decimale() {

    int ndec=0,rem,nbin,base=1;
    printf("Inserire un numero binario che verra' covertito in decimale \n-----> ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    nbin=atoi(input);
    while(nbin>1111111111111111){
        printf("IL NUMERO CHE HAI INSERITO NON E' TROPPO GRANDE\n Inserisci un numero minore\n-----> ");
    }
    int lun = strlen(input);
    
    for(int i=lun-1;i>-1;i--){
        if (input[i] !=49 && input[i] !=48) {
            printf("Il numero inserito non e' un numero binario!!\n Inserire un numero binario\n-----> ");
            scanf("%s", input);
            int lun = strlen(input);
            i =lun;
            }
    }
    nbin=atoi(input);
    int temp = nbin;
    while(temp > 0){
        rem = temp % 10;
        ndec = ndec + rem * base;
        temp = temp / 10;
        base = base * 2;
    }
    printf("Il numero decimale e' %d\n",ndec); 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can approach this, but, if your goal is to read a string containing `'1'`s and `'0'`s and then convert the string in a base 2 conversion to a number, then `strtoul()` provides the direct base 2 conversion you need (it provides base 2 - 36 conversions) with error checking.

On the other hand, `atoi()` provides *zero* error detection or reporting and will happily accept `atoi("my cow");` silently returning `0` with no indication that an error ever occurred.

In like manner, trying to read a string with `scanf()` using `"%s"` without a *field-width* modifier leaves your code wide open to exploit by buffer overrun because `"%s"` will read an unlimited number of characters -- overwriting your array bounds (and off across your program stack). If your array is 15-charaters, then use `"%15s"` to limit the number of characters read to `15` (saving `1` for the nul-terminating character). Or, better, take all user-input with `fgets()` and avoid the pitfalls inherent in new C programmers using `scanf()`.

With the basics out of the way, you simply want to:

- read your user input into a sufficiently sized array (don't skimp on buffer size),
- validate the string provided by the user consist only or `'0'`s and `'1'`s,
- convert the string to an `unsigned long` value using `strtoul()` with `base = 2`, and then
- validate the `strtoul()` conversion by checking that `endptr` does not equal the `numptr` (your `input`) confirming that digits were converted. (`strtoul()` will set `endptr` to point to the next character after the last character used in numeric conversion), and
- validate that overflow or other conversion error did not occur by checking that `errno` is zero after the conversion.

With that as an outline, you can approach your problem as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   /* for strtoul */
#include <string.h>   /* for strspn, strcspn */
#include <errno.h>    /* for errno */

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
  
  char input[MAXC], *endptr = input;    /* input and endptr for strtoul() */
  unsigned long number = 0;             /* number after conversion */
  size_t len;                           /* length of input */
  
  fputs ("enter a binary number: ", stdout);    /* prompt for input */
  if (!fgets (input, MAXC, stdin)) {            /* read/validate input */
    puts ("(user canceled input)");
    return 0;
  }
  
  input[(len = strcspn (input, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save length */
  
  if (strspn (input, "01") != len) {  /* validate input is only 0's and 1's */
    fputs ("error: string must contain only '0' and '1's\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  errno = 0;                                    /* set errno zero */
  number = strtoul (input, &endptr, 2);         /* attempt base 2 converison */
  
  if (endptr == input) {  /* if no digits converted, handle error */
    fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  if (errno) {  /* if error in conversion, handle error */
    fputs ("error: in numeric conversion.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* output results */
  printf ("\nstring : %s\nnumber : %lu\n", input, number);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Does the code identify improper input?

```
$ ./bin/strtoul_bin
enter a binary number: 11101100011112
error: string must contain only '0' and '1's
```

What about the conversion? (removing the `2` above)

```
$ ./bin/strtoul_bin
enter a binary number: 1110110001111

string : 1110110001111
number : 7567
```

Does it handle the user canceling input by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows)?

```
$ ./bin/strtoul_bin
enter a binary number: (user canceled input)
```

Those are three important cases all of your user-input routines should handle. (1) good input, (2) bad input -- handle error, and (3) user canceling input. I'll leave it to you to research `fgets()`. See [man 3 fgetc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) to determine how the manual `EOF` is caught.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.